# Why isn't the if-statement in this ASP.Net Code-behind working?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, controls

I have a dropdown list populated with integers. When "1" is selected, a text box is supposed to appear. I have done something similar in another project, but it won't work here.

Any help is appreciated.

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlHowMany.Items.Add(new ListItem("0", "0"));
        ddlHowMany.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
        ddlHowMany.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
        ddlHowMany.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
    }
}

protected void ddlHowMany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // int howMany = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHowMany.SelectedValue);
    if (ddlHowMany.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        txtGraphic1Desc.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Default.aspx code:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHowMany" runat="server"  
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddlHowMany_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    style="margin-left: 8px" Width="50px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtGraphic1Desc" class="descriptions" runat="server" Height="92px" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Width="328px" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Visible="False">Description of graphic #1</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Your double negative in the title is confusing me. Is the code working or not and do you expect it to be not working or working?

Comment: Ugh, I just saw that. I'm sorry. It's not working at the moment.

Comment: It will work... are you actually posting back the page? If there is no submit button, then you'll need to add `AutoPostBack="true"` to the DDL.

Comment: I have it fixed now. Eventually going to convert to AJAX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to add [autoPostBack="true"](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-DropDownList-OnSelectedIndexChanged-Event.aspx) to dropdownlist.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHowMany" runat="server"  
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddlHowMany_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    style="margin-left: 8px" Width="50px" AutoPostBack="true">
```

Comment: And fix the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` capitalization!

Comment: Is there a setting I can change in Visual Studio so that it adds the capitalization correctly?

Comment: Use Ctrl+A to select all. Then Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F will format those selection to a proper format.